# How to dump a dictionary into an .xlsx file with proper column alignment?

Tags: python, excel, dictionary, xlsxwriter

I have a dictionary with 2000 items which looks like this:

```
d = {'10071353': (0, 0), '06030011': (6, 0), '06030016': (2, 10), ...}
```

Given that I want to write it to an `.xlsx` file, I use this code (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113231/python-write-dictionary-values-in-an-excel-file?answertab=active#tab-top)):

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0
order=sorted(d.keys())
for key in order:
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, col,     key)
    for item in d[key]:
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

This produces an `.xlsx` file with the following alignment:

```
    A           B
    06030001    0
                10

    06030002    10
                10

    06030003    5
                10
```

However, this is the alignment I am after:

```
A           B    C
06030001    0    10

06030002    10   10

06030003    5    10
```

**What should I change in the script to achieve this?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I think should help:

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0

order=sorted(d.keys())
for key in order:
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, col,     key)
    i =1
    for item in d[key]:
        worksheet.write(row, col + i, item)
        i += 1

workbook.close()

IN:

d={'10071353':(0, 0),'06030011':(6, 0),'06030016':(2, 10)

OUT:
A           B    C
06030001    6    0

06030002    2    10

06030003    0    0
```

Answer (score 7):

The best way is to use `pandas` for this task. Some documentation is available here (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html )

```
import pandas as pd


a = {'1':[1,2,3,4], '2':[5,6,7,8]}
a = pd.DataFrame(a)


writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
a.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

You may need to install `xlsxwriter` package

Answer (score 4):

I think you just misplaced a variable.

```
worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        row += 1
```

this is wrong, `row +=1` should be replaced with `col +=1`

This is correct way, You can use the same variable.

```
import xlsxwriter
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('myfile.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()
row = 0
col = 0
order=sorted(d.keys())
for key in order:
    row += 1
    print(key)
    worksheet.write(row, col,     key)
    for item in d[key]:
        print(item,row, col+1)
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, item)
        col += 1
    col = 0
workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]