# How to write JSON **text** to Excel file?

Tags: python, json, excel, pandas, dataframe

Is there any way in Python to write JSON **text** to an Excel file?

Normally I would load JSON response into Pandas dataframe and write the dataframe to Excel:

```
import pandas
form pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import requests

def df_to_excel(df, filename):
    writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(filename)
    df.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()

response = requests.get(url, params).json()
df = json_normalize(response)
df_to_excel(df, 'Response.xlsx')
```

But this requires converting JSON text to Python object, thus replacing `"` with `'`, `false` with `False`, `null` with `None` etc, and I don't want that.

Comment: I suggest just forgetting it's JSON and treating it as a simple string, you can write a string into an Excel cell quite easily. Unless you want to do something more complex? You didn't make clear exactly what the output should look like.

Comment: I would prefer to have JSON keys as columns in Excel and values as rows, so it is easier to just load the file in a dataframe from another module and also for easy browsing of the data. But your method would work as last resort - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert json to dictionary first and then convert to excel file as suggested here [Write dictionary values in an excel file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113231/write-dictionary-values-in-an-excel-file):

```
import json
import xlsxwriter
import requests

response = requests.get(url, params)
d = json.loads(response.text)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('data.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
col = 0

for key in d.keys():
    row += 1
    worksheet.write(row, col, json.dumps(key))
    for item in d[key]:
        worksheet.write(row, col + 1, json.dumps(item))
        row += 1

workbook.close()
```

The key is using `json.dumps()` that converts pythonic format back to json format. For example, `json.dumps(None)` returns `'null'`

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to put JSON into Pandas dataframe as text? I could then easily write the dataframe to Excel.

Comment: As far as I know there's no library that can help you do that. However, you could iterate keys and values of dictionary d applying json.dumps to them and then construct DataFrame from dictionary using pandas.DataFrame.from_dict method. I'm in the road now, I'll add code later if needed. Also add the example of json file you need to convert

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, that is what I thought as well.